# Looking for a counter-example: a degree-one endomorphism of a projective variety which is not an automorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I read on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348128/are-endomorphisms-of-degree-one-always-automorphisms) page that an endomorphism of degree one of a smooth projective algebraic variety must be an automorphism. The proof uses Zariski's main theorem.

My question is this: are there examples of nonsmooth projective algebraic varieties having endomorphisms of degree one that are not automorphisms?

Note that for a morphism, having degree one is equivalent to being birational.

Comment: By “endomorphism of degree one”, do you mean “map of the variety into itself which is an isomorphism at the generic fibre”?

Comment: @Aphelli I guess birationality is equivalent to the condition you mention, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In that case, the morphism from the normalisation of a non normal variety $V$ to $V$ is an example.

Comment: @DamianRössler: I think this misses the “endo” part, no? It’s not a map of the variety to itself…

Comment: @Aphelli. Oups you are right. I wrote too quickly.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about your assumptions? Your linked question assumes projectivity, which for example implies the map to be finite. If you drop this, even the statement for smooth varieties becomes wrong, e.g. $\mathbb C^2 \to \mathbb C^2, (x,y) \mapsto (xy, y)$ is generically an isomorphism, but contracts $\{y=0\}$ to a single point.

Comment: @red_trumpet thanks for pointing this out, I edited the question to include the projectiveness assumption.